# Prove that $x^3+ax+b$ has a double or triple root if and only if $4a^3+27b^2$ = 0

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I do this without doing really annoying algebra? Proving that if $x^3+ax+b$ has a double root, then $4a^3+27b^2 = 0$ is easy, but the other direction seems to involve a lot of algebra and there's probably an easier way.

Comment: It probably helps to note that because the quadratic term is $0$, the sum of the roots (with multiplicities) must also be $0$.

Answer (score 0):

The cubic $p(x)=x^3+ax+b$ has a double root $k$ if and only if $p(k)=0$ and $p'(k)=0$. In other words
$$\begin{cases}k^3+ak+b=0\\3k^2+a=0.\end{cases}$$
Substituting $k^2=-a/3$ into the first equation gives $k=-3b/(2a)$. Substituting into the second equation now gives $27b^2+4a^3=0$. It is easy to see that this logic is reversible, since $p(x)$ has a double root if and only if the simultaneous equations have a solution if and only if $27b^2+4a^3=0$.

Answer (score 0):

We can arrange that the "easy direction" works in fact in both directions. Let us work by enumerating *equivalent statements* from step to step. We have:

- $f=x^3+ax+b$ has at least one root with multiplicity $\ge 0$, iff
- $f$ and $f'$ have a common root, iff
- the resultant of $f$ by $f'$ is zero, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant, first sentences, iff
- the following determinant is zero:
  $$
  \begin{vmatrix}
  1 & 0 & a & b &\\
    & 1 & 0 & a & b\\
  3 & 0 & a & &\\
    & 3 & 0 & a &\\
    &   & 3 & 0 & a \\
  \end{vmatrix} \ .
  $$
  So we only have to compute the above determinant, $\Delta$ say as a matter of notation. Well, it is
  $$
  \begin{aligned}
  \Delta &=
  \begin{vmatrix}
  1 & 0 & a & b &\\
    & 1 & 0 & a & b\\
  3 & 0 & a & &\\
    & 3 & 0 & a &\\
    &   & 3 & 0 & a \\
  \end{vmatrix} 
  \\
  &=
  1\cdot \begin{vmatrix}
   1 & 0 & a & b\\
   0 & a & &\\
   3 & 0 & a &\\
     & 3 & 0 & a \\
  \end{vmatrix} 
  +
  3\cdot 
  \begin{vmatrix}
   0 & a & b &\\
   1 & 0 & a & b\\
   3 & 0 & a &\\
     & 3 & 0 & a \\
  \end{vmatrix} 
  \\
  &=
  a\cdot \begin{vmatrix}
   1  & a & b\\
   3  & a &\\
      & 0 & a \\
  \end{vmatrix}
  -
  3\cdot1\cdot 
  \begin{vmatrix}
   a & b &\\
   0 & a &\\
   3 & 0 & a \\
  \end{vmatrix} 
  +
  3\cdot3\cdot 
  \begin{vmatrix}
   a & b &\\
   0 & a & b\\
   3 & 0 & a \\
  \end{vmatrix} 
  \\
  &=
  a\cdot a\cdot a 
  \begin{vmatrix}
   1  & 1\\
   3  & 1
  \end{vmatrix}
  -
  3a\cdot1\cdot 
  \begin{vmatrix}
   a & b\\
   0 & a 
  \end{vmatrix} 
  +
  3\cdot3\cdot (a^3+3b^2)
  \\
  &=-2a^3-3a^3+9a^3+27b^2
  \\
  &=4a^3+27b^2\ .
  \end{aligned}
  $$

Answer (score 0):

The expansion from the roots ([Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) ) are quite simple in this case
$$
\left( {x - r} \right)\left( {x - s} \right)\left( {x - t} \right) = x^{\,3}  + ax + b\quad  \Rightarrow \quad \left\{ \matrix{
  r + s + t = 0 \hfill \cr 
  rs + rt + st = a \hfill \cr 
   - rst = b \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$

Then assuming, without loss of generality, $r=s$
$$
\eqalign{
  & \left\{ \matrix{
  r + s + t = 0 \hfill \cr 
  rs + rt + st = a \hfill \cr 
   - rst = b \hfill \cr}  \right.\quad  \Rightarrow \quad \left\{ \matrix{
  2r + t = 0 \hfill \cr 
  r^2  + 2rt = a \hfill \cr 
   - r^2 t = b \hfill \cr}  \right.\quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad \left\{ \matrix{
  2r + t = 0 \hfill \cr 
   - 3r^2  = a \hfill \cr 
  2r^3  = b \hfill \cr}  \right.\quad  \Rightarrow \quad \left\{ \matrix{
   - 27r^6  = a^{\,3}  \hfill \cr 
  4r^6  = b^2  \hfill \cr}  \right.\quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad 4a^{\,3}  + 27b^2  = 0 \cr} 
$$

The reverse, is just taking the steps backward.

If $4a^3 + 27b^2 = 0$ then one of the summand is non-negative and the other positive.  In the reals, the non-negative
shall be $27b^2$ and we can put it to equal $24 \cdot 4 \cdot r^6$, and assign the inverse to $4a^3$.
Then we simplify to $a,b$ and add $t$ to equal $-2r$, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a straightforward proof given $4a^3+27b^2 = 0$. Substitute $a=-3\left(\frac {b}{2}\right)^{\frac23}$ and factorize the cubic function explicitly,

$$x^3+ax+b$$
$$=x^3-4b - 3\left(\frac {b}{2}\right)^{\frac23}[x-(4b)^{\frac13}]$$
$$=[x-(4b)^{\frac13}]\left[x^2+(4b)^{\frac13}x+\left(\frac b2 \right)^{\frac23}\right]$$
$$=[x-(4b)^{\frac13}]\left[x+\left(\frac b2 \right)^{\frac13}\right]^2$$

Thus, there is a double root

$$x_{1,2}=-\left(\frac b2 \right)^{\frac13}$$

The proof for the other direction is easier by starting with $(x-s)^2(x-t)=0$ with $s$ being the double root. The vanishing $x^2$ term in $x^3+ax+b=0$ requires $t=-2s$. Then, $a = s^2+2st = -3s^2$ and $b=-2s^3$, leading to the relationship $4a^3+27b^2 = 0$.

Comment: It is not complete. You need to proof if $4a^3+27b^2\ne0$, then it won't have double root

Answer (score 0):

If $u$ is a double root of $f(x) = x^3+ax+b$, then $u$ is also a root of
$f'(x) = 3x^2+a$. If we are to assume that $a$ and $b$ are real numbers, then we must assume that $a \le 0$ and, hence, we can assume that $a=-3u^2$ for some real number $u$.

Then $f(u)=0 \implies u^3-3u^3+b=0 \implies b = 2u^3$.

It follows that $\color{red}{f(x) = x^3-3u^2x + 2u^3}$ and, hence, that $4a^3+27b^2 = 0$

---

Conversely, suppose that $4a^3+27b^2 = 0$.

Looking at the previous argument, it might make things easier if we let
$\color{red}{b = 2u^3}$. Note that the range of the function $u \mapsto 2u^3$ is $\mathbb R$, so we are still covering all possible values of $b$. Then

\begin{align}
   4a^3+27b^2 &= 0 \\
   4a^3 + 27(2u^3)^2 &= 0 \\
   4a^3 + 108u^6 &= 0 \\
   4a^3 &= -108u^6 \\
   a^3 &= -27u^6 \\
   a &= -3u^2
\end{align}

We should therefore have

$$f(x) = x^3+ax+b
       = x^3-3u^2x + 2u^3
       = (x-u)^2(x+2u) \tag{1.}
$$

where the $(x-u)^2$ is there because, from the previous argument, $u$ is supposed to be a double root, and the $(x+2u)$ is there because it makes the constant term equal to $(u^2)(2u) = 2u^3$. Checking the math, we see that equation $(1.)$ is indeed true. So  $u = \sqrt{-\dfrac a3}$ is at least a double root of $x^3+ax+b=0$.